# `docker compose up --build` in a `--parallel` mode

Tags: docker-compose

I can run:

```bash
docker-compose build --parallel
```

Is it possible to run:

```bash
docker-compose up --build
```

with a possibility to pass the `--parallel` flag to the underlying `docker-compose build` run?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `docker-compose up` doesn't accept `--parallel` flag unfortunately. Check [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).

What I usually do is:

```sh
docker-compose build --parallel
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Does this work with the `-f` flag?

Comment: Sorry to say, but Docker docs sucks. Even in `docker build` doc there is no info about `--parallel` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_build/